# variable character field

Tags: sql, oracle

Work in oracle database and new bi here. Just wondering if it is possible to extend variable character defined with length 12 to 64 or more permanently(to hold longer strings), what kind of issues I might see?
I have some programs and files depend on this field. THis is more of general question. A field defined as variable character is because   to extend length in the future?
THanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and very easy, and there are no issues to worry about (at least as long as you work in Oracle; a bit more about that below). It works something like this:

```
create table tbl (x varchar2(10));
insert into tbl values ('mathguy')
alter table tbl modify (x varchar2(20));
```

The issue you may have is with applications in other languages (like Java). If you must load data from Oracle tables to a Java application (say), then the memory reserved for the values from the table is allocated based on the declared length of the strings, not their actual size. So if you change from length 10 to length 4000, about 40 times more memory is allocated for values coming from the table, whether that is really needed or not. This may or may not be an issue, it depends on how RAM-starved your applications are (and what else is happening on the same machine).

Comment: Thanks, what is the reason behind declaring a field as variable character. In this case it is defined as 12, we define as variable so as to extend in the future if there need be ?

Comment: Yes there are java programs that use this field

Comment: "Variable character" means variable length, but if you define `varchar2(12)` that means upper bound of 12 (bytes or characters, depending on how you define and also on defaults). Internally to Oracle, both on disk and in memory, the length is the actual length of the strings, so it doesn't hurt to define everything as `varchar2(4000)`. But if you bulk-load data from Oracle to Java applications and memory may be a concern, you must be aware of that and not be too generous with column definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of varchar has nothing to do with preparing to extend the column size in the future. However, it should be fine to alter the table to increase the field length.

The varchar2 data type is used for fields that can contain a string of variable length--the size of the field is the maximum number of characters that can be stored. As long as your string never exceeds the field length, you should be fine, and may save some space compared to using straight-up char characters.

If you need to extend the field definition to accommodate longer strings, you can use the ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY... syntax. Note that if there is a large amount of data already in the table this may be a costly operation.

```
ALTER TABLE 
   customer 
MODIFY 
   ( 
   cust_name varchar2(100)
   );
```

See the [Oracle Documentation of VARCHAR2 Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822).

Comment: would extending the length of an existing field  or adding a new field with required length would be more costlier?

Comment: If you need to preserve the existing data, then after adding a new column you would need to update all the rows to have the appropriate value, which would be probably more expensive than modifying the column in-place. In general, to prevent confusion it might be clearer to just modify the original column.